# Why does space grow after nodetool compact?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Why does space grow after nodetool compact?

```
Start Finish Size before COMPACT (mb) Size after COMPACT (mb)
16.06.2023 21:00:06 17.06.2023 00:53:56 1 381 270   1 605 130
17.06.2023 00:53:57 17.06.2023 04:47:46 1 381 250   1 589 390
17.06.2023 04:47:46 17.06.2023 08:41:38 1 381 290   1 597 210
```

Size filmed: `nodetool cfstats | grep 'Space used (total)' | awk -F ": " '{s+=$2}END{print s/1000000}'`

Version Cassandra 3.11.6

Comment: What's confusing here is that you have 3 compactions running back to back, however the end size of the previous run, is not the start size of the next run - which logically it would be. Can you provide more details please, compaction command being run, if there are snapshots being created and ideally focus on just 1 table instead of the whole schema.

Comment: I'm sorry, each line is a node with data